# How can I change invoke(new action) under c# 3.0

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, invoke

I made a WinForm program under .Net Framework 4.5

And now I trying to make it under .Net Framework 3.0

Using thread, call the "Control.Invoke" to Datagridview, but it's not work..

My Code is like this

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartAnalyseTheSite));
        th.IsBackground = true;
        th.Start();
    }

    private void StartAnalyseTheSite()
    {
        InsertWebApplicationInfo();
        SelectWebApplicationInfo();
    }

    private void InsertWebApplicationInfo()
    {
         DoSomething...
    }

    private void SelectWebApplicationInfo()
    {
         this.Invoke(new Action(() => { grdWebApplication.DataSource = dtwebApp; }));
    }
```

And

this.Invoke(new Action(() => { grdWebApplication.DataSource = dtwebApp; }));

This code is not work...

Error Message is ->

**'Action' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments**

How can I change that code?? Somebody help me

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it doesn't work? Is there an exception? If so, what does it say? Is there a compile error? Again - if so - what does it say?

Comment: Oh sorry I added it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such code:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { /*Do something*/ }));
```

Comment: **Note 1:** .NET Framework 3.0 uses C# 2.0. C# 2.0 introduces the concept of Anonymous Methods, which permit code blocks to be passed as parameters in place of a separately defined method.

Comment: **Note 2:** To create an equivalent for `new Action(()=>{/*...*/})`, you can first create a delegate this way: `public delegate void Action();` Then to create an instance of that delegate, you can use this code: `new Action(delegate() {/*...*/})`. Since `MethodInvoker` delegate has the signature which we need, so we didn't create a new delegate and used `MethodInvoker`.

Comment: Thank you Reza Aghaei!!
Your code and explanation is perfect! I understood how can use it after read your comment!!